How to find free, readable language-to-language dictionaries
A group of friends and I are working on a project that requires access to downloadable "language-to-language" dictionaries, where words and their corresponding definitions are written in the same language. For example, a Japanese-to-Japanese dictionary would work, where words and their corresponding definitions are both written in Japanese. What we're not looking for is dictionaries like Japanese-to-English dictionaries, where words have their definitions translated to another language (this is all we could find whenever we look for this). The dictionary content must all be in the same language. Other languages like a Swahili, Greek, etc. would work, we want as many dictionaries like these as we can find.
We would also like for these dictionaries to be downloadable and readable in a way that could be accessed by Python.
Where can dictionaries like these be found?

Dictionaries are lots of work, so it shouldn't be surprising that many dictionaries aren't free, especially for less populous languages. But the various language Wiktionaries might fit the bill.
